# Skip several steps if condition is met

Tags: macros, imacros

I am automating the process of downloading information off of a site. As I can only search for (and then download) data from two days at a time, sometimes there is no data to be downloaded.In this instance, when the macro clicks the "download button, the following dialog box appears.

[image]

If there are listings to export, the macro proceeds through selecting a few options and downloading a file. However, if the dialog box above appears I would like the macro to skip the next few steps and proceed to a step several lines ahead. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief, there can be several ways to do that which depend on your browser and 'iMacros'.

 Here is one of them:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

SET msgText "No listings to export"
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:{{msgText}} EXTRACT=TXT

SET nextPos EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/{{msgText}}/) ? '0' : '1';")

' your next steps
TAG POS={{nextPos}} TYPE=A ATTR=...
' ...
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
```

If you play this code in loop mode, it's possible

> to skip the next few steps and proceed to a step several lines ahead.